# textarea can't have a default value

Tags: php, html, textarea

check these lines please

```
<textarea class="wideInput" cols="30" rows="10" value="<?php echo $row['foodDescription']; ?>" ></textarea>
            <input value="<?php echo $row['foodDescription']; ?>" />
```

the input type has the default value, but the textarea doesn't , why please , what is the solution?

Comment: Put the value between the opening and closing textarea tags.

Comment: Textarea doesn't have `value` attribute, try to put its content between the tags. `<textarea>CONTENT</textarea>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `value` attribute

```
<textarea class="wideInput" cols="30" rows="10" ><?php echo $row['foodDescription']; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: i will accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can add value in between `<textarea>` starting and ending tag.

```
<textarea class="wideInput" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $row['foodDescription']; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<textarea class="wideInput" cols="30" rows="10" value="<?php echo $row['foodDescription']; ?>" ></textarea>
```

should be changed to:

```
<textarea class="wideInput" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $row['foodDescription']; ?></textarea>
```

because textarea doesn't have value attribute

Answer (score 2):

Simply put the value in between the textarea tags:

```
<textarea class="wideInput" cols="30" rows="10">
    <?php echo $row['foodDescription']; ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

A textarea isn't like an input, it can't be self-closed (`<textarea/>`), it is self closing tags that can have a value to default display. Just change your code to echo the foodDescription inside the `<textarea></textarea>` tags

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the default value between the tags so:

```
<textarea class="wideInput" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $row['foodDescription']; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be in-between the tags.

```
<textarea class="wideInput" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $row['foodDescription']; ?></textarea>
```

Lol preaching to the choir